# bash while break if current directory is root

Tags: while-loop, sh, root, break

I'm writing a small bash script to call the build script for a website if the current directory is within the website somewhere, so the procedure is to `cd` into the parent directory while the build script isn't in the current directory, and while the current directory isn't `/`.  Then check whether the build script is there and if so, run it.  Here's what I've got:

```
while [ ! -f build-site.py ]
do
    [["`pwd`" == "/"]] && break
    cd ..
done
```

Why isn't this working?  I've tried a few different variations; this one prints out an error message repeatedly until I Ctrl-C it:

`/home/gus/bin/build-site: 7: /home/gus/bin/build-site: [[/: not found`

Comment: Take advantage of available tooling. [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) points out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler as well:

```
until [ -f build-site.py ] || [ "$(exec pwd)" = / ]
do
    cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A space is missing after `[[` (and before `]]`, too).

```
[[ "`pwd`" == "/" ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues pointed out by shellcheck.  Turns out the double square brackets aren't supported by the shell I was running (POSIX) and neither is double equals.  This works:

```
while [ ! -f build-site.py ]
do
    [ $(pwd) = "/" ] && break
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: Double equals is not supported by *any* `[` command, although many do implement it as an undocumented feature... You probably want to add quotes around `$(pwd)`, as well. What happens is `pwd` contains a space for example?